# Use WebView out of a google app/extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webview

I was doing some coding for google extension using webviews, so that way I could interact with the host page (capture links , clicks events, change css and so on). Now Im trying to accomplish the same goal using only a standard html page with javascript. I know that we can`t do that with iframe, so my question is that is that possible to use all the webview features without having  a google app. The bottom line is that I want to run it just like a page in the browser and not run any extra app.

thank you.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is certainly an App-only API.

Comment: and do you know any other way to achieve something like that? thank you.